# Auto updating content in an App from a PHP web service

Tags: php, mysql, cordova, automation

I am making an App using PhoneGap where there is a catalogue of products in a database. This content (image URL's, descriptions, prices etc) is likely to be updated weekly, so I want a way for the app to check the database and see which products are up to date. The idea is that the app should update its self when the phone has a network connection, so the catalogue is up to date.

I was thinking of having a timestamp field for each product which is updated whenever that product is changed, and when the user logs into the app it checks the stored timestamp for that product and checks it against the database. If the server DB is newer than the one on the app it would download info for that product.

Is this an efficient way to keep info up to date, or is there a more effective way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about grab the products with jquery from an API-rest (In the server) and put in a local database like localStorage, indexedDB or SQL-HTML5?

And then use the items from the database.

Comment: Yeah I was planning on using localStorage, but I mean what is the best process to check if your localStorage is up to date compared to the one on the server? Checking local timestamp against server timestamp for each row?

Comment: For ad hoc data like products, I'd use WebSQL instead of LocalStorage. (Btw, IndexedDB is not supported on mobile.) I've got a blog entry that demonstrates syncing local vs remote. http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2012/4/3/Adding-database-synchronization-to-your-PhoneGap-project